# Blender_icons_update.py - SVG icon generation to DAT file issue

Tags: python, compile

I have been trying to run the **python blender_icons_update.py blender_icons.svg** command from command prompt in the \release\datafiles folder, but without any luck. I get these errors:

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Line 10 (in the **blender_icons_update.py**)  when it does the **run(cmd)** in line 33. 
`subprocess.check_call(cmd)`

Something is wrong with the subprocess. What is the fix?

I have correct Python versions installed (2.7 and 3.5.0), Blender 2.79b installed, and... what is missing?

Comment: Development questions about Blender are considered off topic here, you better ask over at https://devtalk.blender.org or on development chat

Comment: Not sure why this is off topic. Edit in a `print(cmd)` statement before line 33.  Going by the error one of the two paths in this command (`cmd`) does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that the paths were not defined for Inkscape and Blender. Both software do not add the PATH environment variables to Windows, so adding them manually made the script file find the correct software to process the *.dat files.